# AngularJS: how to transclude and replace the containing element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I am trying to create a set of AngularJS directives that will conditionally render mutually exclusive segments of block or inline page content. For example, I envisage a mechanism that will render just the nth child element:

```
<selector member="index">
    <div>This div is visible when $scope.index equals 0</div>
    <div>This div is visible when $scope.index equals 1</div>
    <div>This div is visible when $scope.index equals 2</div>
</selector>
```

However, my design requires that the directives are implemented using custom element markup (not attributes applied to HTML elements) and that these HTML-invalid elements are removed from the DOM when rendering is complete. So, in the above example, a single matching `div` element would remain.

As a first attempt to prototype this concept, I converted the built in `ngIf` directive to use the following element-based syntax:

```
<if condition="true">
     <p>This is visible</p>
</if>

<if condition="false">
     <p>This is not visible</p>
</if>
```

Getting this to work simply entailed modifying `restrict` to `E` and changing the name of the watched attribute to `condition`. Here's my modified version of the built-in implementation:

```
application.directive("if", ['$animate', function ($animate) {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function (element, attr, transclude) {
            return function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
                var childElement;
                var childScope;
                    $scope.$watch($attr.condition, function (value) {
                    if (childElement) {
                        $animate.leave(childElement);
                        childElement = undefined;
                    }

                    if (childScope) {
                        childScope.$destroy();
                        childScope = undefined;
                    }

                    if (toBoolean(value)) {
                        childScope = $scope.$new();
                        transclude(childScope, function (clone) {
                            childElement = clone;
                            $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

However, I'm not having much success eliminating the containing `if` element. I suspect I need a much better understanding of how transclusion is intended to work, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation around.

So, if you could either suggest the right technique to use, or point me in the direction of some relevant tutorials, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Have you looked at [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch)? It's sort of made for this purpose.

Comment: @OverZealous: yes, you're right that ngSwitch is a good model for this. However, although it supports both element and attribute modes, the element mode leaves an <ng-switch> element in the page, which is not valid HTML and is the specific problem that I am trying to overcome.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't replace what you want?

```
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true, // ** //
```

That will replace the `if` with your `content`

Comment: Unfortunately the "replace" option appears only to work when a template is defined, in which case the original element is replaced with the rendered template. In my example above, setting replace: true has no effect. This could still be a part of the solution, but I think there must be an extra step required to manipulate or populate that template via the "compile" or "link" function.

Comment: Why are you addiment about using the Element, you know you can use a comment?

Comment: For some of the directives that I need to create, the containing element will also enclose nested directive elements (e.g. like ngSwitch) and we want to create a consistent syntax across all directives.